# Overwrite the current theme in YII

Tags: php, yii, themes

So i'm messing since long time to overwrite the current theme. For some reasons i need to include the new theme in from my  controller and that why i need to change the current activate theme.How can i overwrite the **theme** index value of main function of environment.php

```
private function _main() {
 return array(
            // Base Path
            'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
            // Theme Name
            'theme' => 'front_theme',
}
```

Now in  controller I want to change the theme from **front** to **user_theme**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final i found the solution. TO overwrite the current activated theme, you need to create the init function in your controller and give the name of your new theme. Here is the code:

```
public function init()
    {
       Yii::app()->theme = 'user';
       parent::init();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii 1 you have different ways to configure the theme that is being used.

You can have a dynamic way, as you've found, by initialising the `Yii::app()->theme` property method in the `init()` method.

Or you can set the theme globally for the application, which is probably the one I would suggest to use, unless you have specific requirements, in the `config/main.php`:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'theme' => 'mytheme'
    // ...
)
```

This will pick up the theme you want to use from `/themes/mytheme/` and fallback to `/protected/views/` if the template is not found in the first.

As last word of advice, if you're starting a brand new project I'd suggest to start directly with Yii 2 rather than Yii 1, as it's now the preferred and more up-to-date framework version.